# Como baixar vídeos do youtube e convertê-los para mp3 usando ruby?

Tags: ruby, youtube, download

Preciso de uma forma simples em ruby, que permita baixar vídeos do youtube só que preciso apenas do áudio do vídeo (mp3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode usar o [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) para fazer isso, e usando Ruby ficaria simples.

```
system("youtube-dl -t --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{id_do_video}")
```

caso você queira baixar todos os vídeos de um canal, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
require 'httparty'

quantidade_maxima = 50
canal = 'nome_do_canal'

#1,51,101 são usado para paginação, como a api do youtube só permite que você traga apenas 50 vídeos por vez.
[1,51,101].each do |offset|
  feed = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(HTTParty.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=#{canal}&max-results=#{quantidade_maxima}&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=published&start-index=#{offset}").body)
  feed["data"]['items'].each do |video|
    system("youtube-dl youtube-dl -t --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{video['id']}") rescue puts "erro"
  end
end
```

Espero ter ajudado.